# Problems with layout of 3,5 inch iphone screen

Tags: ios, layout, screen

I'm trying to add an iAd banner which I set just above a `UITabBar`, and it works perfectly on 4 inch screens, but when I test it on 3,5 inch the banner is totally invisible.

Is there a simple way to fix all the views so that everything will be scaled to the 3,5 inch screen if needed?
I've found a tutorial saying to set the "size" of the "Simulated Metrics", under the Attribute Inspector of the view to freeform, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Auto layout or resizing?

Comment: @Wain what's the difference?

Comment: Well, you need to pin to the bottom in both cases, but how you configure it is quite different.

Comment: @Wain cool, i did the pin bottom space to superview and it appeared but i see that if there were "things" in that place, they will be covered. Should i insert constraints?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify constraints for how all of the screen contents moves or resizes and the available space changes. The banner view need to be pinned to the bottom and you will need a view somewhere to be pinned to other views but have a flexible height.